Why do phrases "By fair means or foul" and "By hook or by crook" have such different use of preposition 'By'?
Both idioms have pretty much the same meaning. Both are centuries old idioms. However, one uses preposition 'by' twice while the other doesn't. Why? Can someone please explain what am I missing here?

Is there a reason two idioms should match?

The first is using adjectives, the second has nouns. Idioms are what they are, not proscribed.

Each of the idioms uses a perfectly valid construct involving by, they just happen not to be the same construct. And the syntactic pattern ADJ N or ADJ is old and almost never used today excepting in such fixed expressions. Compare to Shakespeare’s good men and true (from Much Ado About Nothing), which is sometimes used to describe members of a jury.
By the way, one could just as easily grumble that the second idiom was redundant since hook and crook are all but synonymous. But their synonymy is, no doubt, part of the expression’s initial appeal. It and their rhyming account for its staying power.
